# Android Studio Dolphin Gradle sync error - java.util.List org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.roots.ProjectRootUtilsKt.findAll

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, intellij-plugin

Below is the Gradle error I am getting with the Dolphin upgrade. Any help appreciated.

```
 Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738, built on September 1, 2022 Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 aarch64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. macOS 12.6 GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation Memory: 2048M[![enter image description here][1]][1] Cores: 8 Registry:
        external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
        ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
        ide.instant.shutdown=false
    
    Non-Bundled Plugins:
        com.github.grishberg.android.android-layout-inspector-plugin (22.09.16.0)
```

[image: 'java.util.List org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.roots.ProjectRootUtilsKt.findAll(com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.DataNode, com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.Key)']

Answer (score 3):

Just uninstall completely any Android Studio before installing Dolphin version.

It seems the error come from Kotlin plugin. If you install Dolphin on top of Chipmunk, Dolphin does not remove previous jar libs in folder C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\Kotlin\lib

So some classes/templates are defined in 2 different jar and Android Studio is lost and refuse to build project.

Error in idea.log:

```
2022-10-05 10:18:41,131 [  43352]  ERROR - e.fileTemplates.impl.FTManager - Assertion failed: Duplicate bundled template Kotlin Worksheet.kts [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar!/fileTemplates/internal/Kotlin Worksheet.kts.ft, jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-idea.jar!/fileTemplates/internal/Kotlin Worksheet.kts.ft] 
java.lang.Throwable: Assertion failed: Duplicate bundled template Kotlin Worksheet.kts [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar!/fileTemplates/internal/Kotlin Worksheet.kts.ft, jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-idea.jar!/fileTemplates/internal/Kotlin Worksheet.kts.ft]
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.assertTrue(Logger.java:218)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.impl.FTManager.createAndStoreBundledTemplate(FTManager.java:208)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.impl.FTManager.setDefaultTemplates(FTManager.java:197)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.impl.FileTemplatesLoader.loadConfiguration(FileTemplatesLoader.java:168)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.impl.FileTemplatesLoader.lambda$new$0(FileTemplatesLoader.java:63)
```

**OR** If you don't want to uninstall Android Studio, try to "clean" the folder C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\Kotlin\lib (I didn't tested it)

You should only have those files:
[image: lib folder]

And jps folder:
[image]

Comment: Your 2nd approach didn't work for me, but the 1st did the job.